# DELETE from table based on SELECT query with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I want to delete some records based on records that I got from other query. Problem is that I have syntax error that I can't solve.

Here is query that I am using:

```
DELETE FROM `tickets` as c 
WHERE c.TICKET_ID IN ( SELECT a.TICKET_ID 
FROM `tickets` as a 
INNER JOIN `old_tickets` as b 
ON b.TICKET_ID = a.TICKET_ID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need IN clause it could be done with just join as

```
delete c from tickets c
join old_tickets oc on oc.TICKET_ID = c.TICKET_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM tickets as a 
INNER JOIN old_tickets as b ON b.TICKET_ID = a.TICKET_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove Join in your subquery as anyhow you are checking for all TICKET_ID's from ticket1 which have matches in old_tickets table;

So that your query becomes:

```
DELETE FROM tickets t1
 WHERE t1.TICKET_ID IN (SELECT t2.TICKET_ID
                        FROM old_tickets t2)
```